# javascript form sent issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form in html, i have an optional field membership ID in which if enter field data it sends the field, if i delete the field and submit it sends the previous data,but i dont need to send membership field if there is no data

my code:

```
                        data.firstName = reg_name;
                        data.lastName = reg_name_l;
                        data.email = reg_mail;
                        data.phoneNumber = country_list+reg_ph;
                        data.dateOfBirth = reg_dob;
                        data.description = reg_snap;
                        data.price = reg_price;
                        data.EAP = EAP;
                        data.state = state;
                        data.organization = org_value;
                        if(org_value = "LPCANC" && mem_id){
                            data.membershipId = mem_id;
                        }
                        // }else{
                        //  data.membershipId = "Null";
                        // }
                        console.log(mem_id);
                        console.log(data.membershipId);                     
                        console.log(data.country);
                        data.specialities = specialities;
                        data.certifications = certification_Array;
                        data.insurance = insurance_array;
                        data.educations = education_Array;
                        data.image = profimg;
                        data_Array.push(data);
                        //form.append("image", this.files[s], this.files[s].name);
                        form.append("data", JSON.stringify(data));
                        console.log(data_Array);
                        console.log(data);
```

I don't need to send data.membershipid if there is no data, but it sends with previous value.

Comment: If you don't want to send the field at all, you can delete the field `delete data.membershipid` in the else part. This way it will be deleted from the JSON.

Comment: You may have to set the scope of data well or delete the unwanted property before sending

Comment: you can reset the form fields using $('selector').reset(). it will reset your all fields as a null so after your submit call reset your form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(org_value == "LPCANC" && mem_id){    
    data.membershipId = mem_id;
  }
  else{
     delete data.membershipId
  }
```

*Note: Use double `==` signs for comparison*